# Cant point the domain to the Ubuntu 18.04 server

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, ubuntu-18.04, vps

I have the domain and the VDS server on the same provider. The server is running on Ubuntu 18.04.

I have the Vue app running on `nginx`.

It works with the `IP` of the server and i want to link the domain to it.
It does not work despite of the fact that I followed instructions.

*'mydomain' is given for example it is a replacement*

On the domain DNS I have the CNAME record:

**Name:** *www.mydomain.xyz.*

**Type:** CNAME

**TTL:** 14400

**VALUE:** mydomain.xyz

This is the value of the file `/etc/nginx/sites-available/default`

```
server {
    listen 80;
    #listen [::]:80 default_server;
    server_name www.mydomain.xyz;

    root /var/www/html/dist;

    index index.html;

    location / {
        root /var/www/html/dist;
        try_files $uri /index.html;
    }

    error_log /var/log/nginx/vue-app-error.log;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/vue-app-access.log;
}
```

May be I missed something ?

Comment: What is the action you perform that yields an unexpected result? What is the result of this action? What do you see in the nginx logs?

Comment: I don’t  have any error or any warning everything works perfectly
using the server ip the app runs and works but the domain cant be attached and i think i am missing some important part and don't know about it :/